# Adding own SQLite database at the end of already existing

Tags: android, database, sqlite

Good day, i made my own SQLite Android database and used it with the help of Android-sqlite-asset-helper lib ([Android SQLite Helper lib](https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-sqlite-asset-helper)). 
Now i want to upgrade it, but not to delete and put another. I want to put another own SQLite database with the same fields but diff data at the end of existing database. 
The lib allows only delete your old dbase and create new. 
Thanks for your help!

Comment: Can't you simply **insert new rows** into the existing database?

Comment: I had filled database, i'm looking a way to add the whole database. I did not work with SQLite, so I don't know how to parse own database file, or how to do it. If you can, please give me some articles or smth. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: I guess you already know that you have to programmatically copy the db from the assets folder to the `/data/data/...` path, if not already existing. Once the db is there, you can perform any CRUD operations on it. Including adding new rows to it (it's the **C** of CRUD).

Comment: The main thing that I dont want to add rows one by one coz there are 300 of them or more, I'm trying to put the whole new db file that I have at data folder at the end of the database that i using now. Maybe I misunderstand smth, please, give me an example how to do smth like this. Thanks for your answer!

Comment: So, why don't you modify the "old" database, add the records to it (from a CSV, I suppose), then re-put the database where it was?

Comment: Coz it has changes made by user, and I dont want to overwrite it by default values.

Comment: You don't have to `to overwrite it by default values`. You have to **add** the new rows, not to **update** the existing ones.

Comment: okay, for example. I have database 1. Jack|12.12.2000|0. Then user changes 0 to 1 and get  Jack|12.12.2000|1. He stores it at his phone, i dont know his data, and then a need add Mike. If i will write "Jack" that i have and new Mike to new DB i will erase data that user changed. That's the problem. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Can't Jack and Mike be stored on the same table? If 0 is the id, you surely don't want to modify it. Or you will loose the relations between the other tables...

Comment: no, this is the same table, and 0 is not an id, its an example. So all that i need its add my own database to already set in app.

Comment: Still I can't figure why you want to complicate your life by using 2 databases when you can use just 1...

Comment: I should add some information after month or year, thats why.

Comment: Listen. I use databases since a whole lifetime. It's really a nonsense to make a second database just to add some rows. Do you fear to loose data while inserting new rows? You originally have `Jack|12.12.2000|0`. The user modifies Jack to `Jack|12.12.2000|1`. Then  you add `Mike|11.11.2008|0`. What you have right now? `Jack|12.12.2000|1` **and** `Mike|11.11.2008|0`

Comment: We do not understand each other) i made a database, post app at play market, than user downloads it with this bd. User making changes in this bd, I DONT KNOW WHAT DID HE CHANGE. Then i should add aditional data to database, and do not remove changes that user did in db(i have only database with MY default data, not user's, it keeps on his phone). Thanks a lot for your answers, i really appreciate, but i think i found answer [here](https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-sqlite-asset-helper/issues/53)